# How to get browser proxy from NPAPI plugin, without using xpcomglue?

Tags: firefox, plugins, xpcom, npapi, npruntime

I am developing a plugin, and I need to get browser proxy for a given 
host.

Right now it works using *nsIProtocolProxyService*. However, the *NewURI* 
function (needed to construct an URI object, used by 
*nsIProtocolProxyService::resolve()*) takes a const reference to 
*nsACString*. And it looks like, for any concrete implementation of it 
I need to link with **xpcomglue**, which I cannot do (If I understand it 
right, I shouldn't link dynamically for techincal 
reasons; and I cannot link statically with xpcomglue_s for legal 
reasons).

So, how can I get browser proxy **without linking with xpcomglue**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely a tricky question.  Really, the best way (when possible) is to use the NPN_GetURL/NPN_PostURL style NPAPI functions when possible.  If that's not possible, you're more or less up a creek unless you can rely on a recent browser version.

If you can assume a recent version of Firefox / gecko API (I'm pretty sure Firefox 3.6 supports this, but not certain which started; docs say gecko SDK 1.9, but I don't think it was there at that point) then you can use [NPN_GetValueForURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NPN_GetValueForURL) with NPNURLVProxy to get the proxy information for a given URL.

Again, keep in mind that this will only work on newer browsers, and I haven't had a chance to compile a compatibility matrix on what supports it yet; I have plans to add this to [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org), but it didn't make it into 1.4 so it may be another month before I get to it.

As a failover option, the most common solution if this isn't available is to simply get the proxy configuration for WinInet (internet explorer) and trust that it will be the same.

This is (IMO) a significant issue without a really good fix.  This is the reason that Flash is notoriously fickle with network access across proxies as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I _think_ I can target 3.6, so it's exactly the answer I was asking for (don't have "reputation" to vote your answer up).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be developing NPAPI plugins that use XPCOM; see [Mozilla's docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Plugins). Perhaps you could use a Firefox extension for at least part of what you are trying to do, and communicate between that and your plugin using JS bindings.

Comment: Why? I expose plugin scripting via npruntime, but I thought I can still call mozilla services via XPCOM.

Comment: because it won't work on anything but firefox -- not on Chrome, Safari, Opera, etc.

Comment: Ok, I see. Well, I'll have to leave with it for now.